# Chartjs update layout size

Tags: javascript, height, chart.js

I would to decrease the height between my legend and the bottom of the axis X of my chartjs instance. I can't find any solution in the documentation of chartjs.

You can see in this image the yellow zone which I need to decrease.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a working example of your code?

Comment: Yes for sure, Is not exactly the same data but you can see this on my jsfiddle :https://jsfiddle.net/YvanBarbaria/34m97pao/40/

Comment: @JohnBaker any news ?